# Withdraw all employees with the maximum bonus in each month. MAX(SUM) GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to Withdraw all employees with the maximum bonus in each month?

I have table:

```
id_prem id_emp  months                  premium
1       1       2016-01-01 00:00:00.000 3000
3       1       2016-01-01 00:00:00.000 2000
5       1       2016-03-01 00:00:00.000 3000
6       1       2016-01-16 00:00:00.000 3000
8       1       2016-01-11 00:00:00.000 2000
7       2       2016-02-14 00:00:00.000 5000
2       2       2016-02-01 00:00:00.000 5000
4       3       2016-02-01 00:00:00.000 1000
9       3       2016-02-09 00:00:00.000 1000
```

It is necessary to sum the bonus of each employee in each month and get the maximum bonus
As a result, get only those employees who have the maximum bonus in each month

My query:

```
SELECT id_emp, mon, MAX(sum_prem) as max_premium
FROM(SELECT id_emp, month(months) as mon, SUM(premium) as sum_prem FROM Employee.Emp_prem 
GROUP BY id_emp, month(months))as t 
GROUP BY id_emp, mon
```

Result:

```
id_emp mon  max_premium
1      1    10000
2      2    10000
3      2    2000
1      3    3000
```

This is not the right result.

I need as a result to display only the maximum bonus in each month.

Comment: Most DBMSes support `RANK`/`ROW_NUMBER`

Comment: Tag your quesiton with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want aggregation with window functions.  Something like this:

```
select e.*
from (select id_emp, year(months) as yyyy, month(months) as mm, sum(premium) as premium,
             row_number() over (partition by year(months), month(months) order by sum(premium) desc) as seqnum
      from Employee.Emp_prem 
      group by id_emp, year(months), month(months)
     ) e
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: @БулатХуснутдинов Be sure to ACCEPT Gordon's answer.  It is a simple way to show your appreciation for his time and talent.